# SQL Server query on nvarchar with asterisk in data and in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Product` which looks like this:

`Name (nvarchar(100), not null)`

It has data that looks like this:

`4503-U**F19`

When I query like this: 
`select * from Product where Name = '4503-U**F19'`

I get nothing back... what gives?

Is there some special way to escape a where clause that contains an asterisk?

I'm probably staring at the answer and can't see it.

Comment: "Looks like this" or is exactly that? The asterisk is in no way special in a simple comparison like yours. Most likely cause is that the data is not equal.

Comment: A strong possibility is that the hyphen is not the same type.

Comment: The code you posted would return the data you stated you have. You need to post a reproducible example.

Comment: Open Notepad++ and go to View>Show Symbol>"Show all characters" and confirm that the strings are actually the same.

Comment: What collation are you using?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260(v=sql.105).aspx  .... try CAST([Name] AS VARCHAR(100))

Comment: Yeah I'm unable to reproduce given the strings provided. Seems like a unicode issue.

Comment: @JacobH There was a CRLF at the end of the text. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem, that's my go-to stop #1 when I can't figure out rogue characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the N in the prefix?

```
select * from Product where Name = N'4503-U**F19'
```